# Simplest way to update a document in a Solr database

Tags: solr

The XML format required by Solr to [insert a document](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) differs from that used to [retrieve a document](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XMLResponseFormat). The simple use case of updating the value of one field requires rewriting the entire document.

The only difference is that data types are reflected in the query format, e.g. `<int name="foo">5</int>` but the submission format uses `<field>` tags for everything.

Is there some option to avoid the legwork of changing all these tags, while still using HTTP + XML?

In other words, I would like Solr to either accept `<int>` tags in HTTP POST bodies or return `<field>` tags in GET bodies. (Omitting the header from the response would be nice, too.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main concern is simulating an in-place update.

Is XSLT powerful enough to transform Solr's XML response to an XML format more compatible with Solr's update format? There is [XSLT response writer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter) which rewrites Solr's response to other formats. Sorry, but I am not familiar enough with XSLT.

---

**Kludgy Method 2** The JSON updaters and response writers (same for CSV, AFAIK) use syntax consistent with each other. Would you be willing to work with JSON/CSV in intermediate formats?

---

On Solr's **response writers** (XML, XSLT, JSON, CSV and others):
http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Response+Writers

On updating JSON:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

On updating CSV:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV

Comment: Yes, I'm considering JSON too, but that's kind of going out of my way. I plan to write an XSLT later on to make the `name` attributes into the tag names, but for now I don't know enough either.